# Javascript - Looping through elements on the array, then next elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd need to construct HTML table based arrays. I'm almost here but stuck in one point. Let me try to explain:

I already could construct the header of the table, with as many column as I need, OK

**rowLength** = 2 in my case, OK - > so I need to create two data rows

**notUniq** = 8 the full number of ma elements

**arrayLength** = 4, basically that is the table header column number.

**Answers** is an array, with 8 element: Adela Cervantsz,true,Dell,Good lapotp please,false,Barton Friesner,iOS please,IPad

So part of my code:

```
    for (var k = 0; k < rowLength; k++) {
            string += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < notUniq; j++) {
                string += "<td style=" + "width: 5%; font-size:70%" + ">" + Answers[j] + "</td>";
            }
            string += "</tr>";
        }
```

It produces me:
[Please click to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE9gU.png)
So it crates 2 rows, ok, but each row has 8 columns, not ok, I'd need just the first 4 element, then the 2nd 4 element.

If I modify the code, so if "for" with arrayLength 4 times, so the code is:

```
    for (var k = 0; k < rowLength; k++) {
            string += "<tr>";
            for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {
                string += "<td style=" + "width: 5%; font-size:70%" + ">" + Answers[j] + "</td>";
            }
            string += "</tr>";
        }
```

Then I get 2 rows, OK, 4 columns, OK, but both row has the same values :( Fors sure I'd need 1st row is the first 4 elements, the 2nd row is the next 4 elements..
[Please click here to check the 2nd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhwy4.png)

Could you help me on this? I gues I'd need modify / extend somehow the Answers[l] part, to get the first 4, then the next.
Really appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the arrays in your question please?

Answer (score 0):

You must consider the row index in the Answers array. Each new row, the index must be increased by arrayLength. **Answers[k*arrayLength + j]** should do the trick

```c
for (var k = 0; k < rowLength; k++) {
    string += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {
        string += "<td style=" + "width: 5%; font-size:70%" + ">" + Answers[k*arrayLength + j] + "</td>";
    }
    string += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, almost! ::) With this I get ther result of two rows, first line is 0 1 2 3 , 2nd line is 4 5 6 7 . So add the indexnumbers, not the text values. I try to figure it out, if any help welcome!

Comment: I don't understand, isn't this exactly what you wanted. This generates the same output as the answer below.

Comment: Youa are right Manuel, sorry my fault was that, not copied the same value you commented. It is also perfect. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
var length = i = 0;
for (var k = 0; k < rowLength; k++) {
     length+=arrayLength;
     string += "<tr>";
     for (var j = i; j < length; j++) {
          string += "<td style=" + "width: 5%; font-size:70%" + ">" + Answers[j] + "</td>";
     }
     string += "</tr>";
     i+=arrayLength;   
 }
```